# I'm relatively new to Excel VBA, and I'm not sure what code I need

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA, and have run into a "not knowing what code I need" section. I might have used the wrong terminology in my explanation, I apologize in advance.

The gold and green on the JCX sheet is manual formatting for clarification.

For starters, the gold cell with 50 is in the correct column (CFM), but the wrong row. From the relationship in the 08-Attribute Sheet, that 50 CFM needs to be on the row with AHU-2 (along with the other values for AHU-2). I'm having issues creating this "relationship" in VBA.

After loading the first CFM value, if something relates to AHU-2, and goes in either the SP, RPM, or Motor HP columns...then that numerical value needs to go in the appropriate column in the AHU-2 row. Not the next row in the correct column.

If it's not one of those 4 "categories", then it goes in the "UDF" columns, which start at column 20. Again, keeping the relationship with the "tag", which we'll keep to AHU-2 for now.

The #### that VBA is also returning when one of those 4 main categories fails, is just a compressed #REF!. I didn't expand it before taking the screenshot.

**08-Attribute Sheet**
[image: 08-Attribute Sheet]

**JCX Sheet**
[image: JCX Sheet]

```
TagRowCounter = 2
AttributeRowCounter = 2
TagNumberRow = 2
TagValueNameColumn = 20
TagValueColumn = 21

TagRowCounter = 2
Do
    Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagRowCounter, 14).Value = Application.VLookup(Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagRowCounter, 1), Sheets("08-Attribute").Range("A:K"), 1, 0)

        If Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9) = "CFM" Then
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, 14).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11).Value

            ElseIf Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9) = "SP" Then
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, 15).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11).Value

            ElseIf Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9) = "RPM" Then
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, 16).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11).Value

            ElseIf Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9) = "Motor_HP" Then
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, 17).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11).Value

            Else
                'Tag Value Name
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, TagValueNameColumn).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, TagValueNameColumn).Value
                'Tag Value Number
                Sheets("JCX").Cells(TagNumberRow, TagValueColumn).Value = Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, TagValueColumn).Value
            End If
                TagValueNameColumn = TagValueNameColumn + 2
                TagValueColumn = TagValueColumn + 2
                TagRowCounter = TagRowCounter + 1
                TagNumberRow = TagNumberRow + 1
                AttributeRowCounter = AttributeRowCounter + 1

Loop Until Sheets("08-Attribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 1) = False
```

Comment: Might I suggest a `Case Select Sheets("08-Attrribute").Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9)`, and then `Case "CFM"`, `Case "SP"`.... `Case Else` in my opinion it improves readability of your code and works the same as all those `If Then ElseIf Then` statements

Comment: @SilentRevolution I'll take a look at that, thanks for the tip. Any idea what I'm missing though?

Comment: `####` typically just means the column is too narrow to display the full value

Comment: @TimWilliams I expanded that column, and it changed to a #REF!. Makes me think the logic is wrong.

Comment: Your VLookup is not correct - the lookup table should have the match attribute as the first column, and must contain the column from which you want to return values (so in your case it must be at least 10 columns wide).  You're only using Column J for the table.

Comment: @TimWilliams I changed the VLookup, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops were off and your lookup was off.

The manner of matching the tag number on sheet JCX with the AttributeID on the sheet 08-Attribute does not work but your counters count on so you get data in the wrong places. Try this refactored cleaned up code below and try to work out what it does step by step.

```
Dim TagRowCounter As Long
Dim AttributeRowCounter As Long
Dim ws08Attribute As Worksheet
Dim wsJCX As Worksheet

Set ws08Attribute = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("08-Attribute")
Set wsJCX = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JCX")

'First loop goes down the list of the attributes on the 08-Attributes sheet
For AttributeRowCounter = 2 To ws08Attribute.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    'Within the first loop the second loop goes down the list of Tag numbers on the JCX sheet
    For TagRowCounter = 2 To wsJCX.Cells(2, 10).End(xlDown).Row
        'If an attributeID from sheet 08-Attributes matches with a Tag number on the JCX sheet then record the value
        If wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 10) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 1) Then
            Select Case ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9)
                Case "CFM"
                    wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 14) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)
                    Exit For
                Case "SP"
                    wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 15) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)
                    Exit For
                Case "RPM"
                    wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 16) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)
                    Exit For
                Case "Motor HP"
                    wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 17) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)
                    Exit For
                Case Else
                    'If no UDF value has been recorded simply record value in col 20 and 21
                    If wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 20) = Empty Then
                        wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 20) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9)
                        wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 21) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)

                    'Otherwise look for the first empty cell behind col 20 and 21
                    Else
                        wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 20).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 9)
                        wsJCX.Cells(TagRowCounter, 20).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = ws08Attribute.Cells(AttributeRowCounter, 11)
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
    Next TagRowCounter
Next AttributeRowCounter
```

Comment: Why did you define TagRowCounter and AttributeRowCounter As Long? Just curious. VBA won't let me run it with those Dims above, along with my defined Dims up top.

Comment: It is a habit. The way you declare your variables they become variants, i.e. they can be anything. I'm declaring my variables as a type, in this case long, could also be integer, but integers only go up to 2,147,483,647 while long can go up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,80. Declaring your type is supposed to be more efficient as the program doesn't have to guess what type it is and it also prevents misuse of the variable as i now cannot accidentally load a string value into it.

Comment: The reason for not being able to run the code with both variable declarations is that most likely you're double declaring variables. Always keep your variable declarations together. This way it is easier to spot if you've used the same variable in two or more declarations.

Comment: That code you posted doesn't do anything on my end, not on the JCX sheet at least.

Comment: Also I've added a bit of explanation to the loops.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are both sheets in the same document?

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't know the cycle took that long. I'm holding down F8 for a while, and things are popping up every so often. No errors, just a long time to see results.

Comment: Well think about it, for each value on the list on sheet 08-Attribute, it has to go through every single value on the list on sheet JCX and only if the two values match, something is recorded. I've added an escape from the inner loop if a match is made to improve efficiency.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. It only took Excel about .1 second to run it normal speed. Thanks!

Comment: BTW in VBA integer is 2 bytes and long 4 bytes. The number ranges you mentioned are for Long and Decimal (12 bytes)

Comment: @Slai, My bad, I assumed VBA types to be the same as VB types [Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type) and [Integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to copy values from a "look up" table into a single row on a "report" sheet.

The reason you're getting a #REF result from your function is that nothing meets your criteria in the vLookup--see Microsoft documentation for [vlookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel). SilentRevolution provide the fix for that.

One thing  you could do to speed up the calculation process is to use an Excel Table with the Index/Match worksheet functions. You'd need to define the table on worksheet 08-Attribute as an Excel Table -- [jkp-ads](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) or [thespreadsheetguru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

To enter the index formula below copy and paste it into the CFM column.  Then press the Contrl key, the Shift Key and the Enter Key together. (Ctl-Shft-Enter).  This saves the formula as an [Excel Array Formulae](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).  MOST IMPORTANT, if you want to maintain the column names you cannot drag the formula.  You have to copy then past the formula.  If you drag and drop the column names move to the next column just like copying a cell reference would.

The index/match formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(tbl80Attrib[AttributeValue],MATCH($J5&N$2,tbl80Attrib[AttributeID]&tbl80Attrib[AttributeName],0)),"")`

After you press Ctl-Shft-Enter, the formula will have {} around it and look like 
`{=IFERROR(INDEX(tbl80Attrib[AttributeValue],MATCH($J5&N$2,tbl80Attrib[AttributeID]&tbl80Attrib[AttributeName],0)),"")}`  NOTE: you cannot enter the {}, the Ctl-Shft-Enter causes Excel to do this creating and array formula.

Then all your code has to do is deal with the undefined values.